# how to when i stop thread (Mythread.stop();) and i go to do someting and then i want to use thread again

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 Thread td = new Thread(){
       public void run(){
        //do someting
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               ///// do something
              td.stop();
        }
};
  public static void main(String[] args){
       //do someting this line
       td.start();
      /////do  new someting this line
      td.start();

}
```

when I start program I want do  1. > 2. >2.1 >3. >4 
how I do this

Comment: You should never use `Thread#stop`, see [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for details.  Threads are also not reentrant, that is, they can't be re-started

Comment: You don't need to call stop() at the end, it will stop at the end anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stop()`, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29), is deprecated and should never be used. And a Thread can be started only once ([as documented as well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once.

I suggest you read the Thread javadoc, as well as the [concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

It seems you want to wait in the started thread until some operation is done in the main thread. Your description is too vague to give a definitive answer, but you should look at Lock and CountDownLatch in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: +1 I would argue you can stop() in the current thread if you know what you are doing, but it is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

```
use 'thread.sleep' or wait and notify
```

http://www.javatpoint.com/inter-thread-communication-example

Answer (score 0):

stop() is deprecated but you can acheive this pause and resume functionality as below:

Following sample code will give behavior like thread is getting paused and resumed:

```
public abstract class PausableTask implements  Runnable{

 private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 private Future<?> publisher;
 protected volatile String state;
 private void someJob() {
  System.out.println("Job Done :- " + state);

 }

 abstract void task();

 @Override
 public void run() {
  while(!Thread.currentThread().interrupted()){
   task();  
  }
 }

 public void start(){
  publisher = executor.submit(this);
  state = "started";
 }

 public void pause() {
  publisher.cancel(true);
  state = "paused";
 }

 public void resume() {
  // you won't see this state
  state = "resumed";
  start();
 }

 public void stop() {
  state = "stoped";
  executor.shutdownNow();
 }
}
```

For further details more sample code is given here on this link:

http://handling-thread.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/pause-and-resume-thread.html